# android pass List<Spreadsheet> between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, google-sheets-api, serializable

I am working with the google sheets api (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) and I am trying to pass a class that I created that contains only a List, and implements Serializable.

**here is the SerializableSpreadsheetList class:**

```
public class SerializableSpreadsheetList implements Serializable {

    private List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets;


    public SerializableSpreadsheetList(List<SpreadsheetEntry> list){
        this.spreadsheets=list;
    }

    public List<SpreadsheetEntry> getSpreadsheets() {
        return spreadsheets;
    }


}
```

**and the code for starting the activity:**

```
mUpdatePracticeIntent.putExtra("isSpreadsheetsSet", true);
SerializableSpreadsheetList SerializableList=new SerializableSpreadsheetList(mSpreadsheets);
mUpdatePracticeIntent.putExtra("Spreadsheets", SerializableList);

startActivity(mUpdatePracticeIntent);
```

the app crashes when I am trying to start the activity.

**Here is the Logcat:**

```
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.keeptrack.SerializableSpreadsheetList)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1176)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1130)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:488)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1552)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:502)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5659)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1411)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1377)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2833)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2959)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at com.example.keeptrack.HomeActivity$2.onClick(HomeActivity.java:112)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2585)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9299)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696): Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1535)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:973)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1219)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1143)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:413)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1241)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1689)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1653)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1171)
02-18 18:03:40.280: E/AndroidRuntime(17696):    ... 21 more
```

what am I doing wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: `SpreadsheetEntry` is not serializable

Comment: thanks for your reply, so in what way can I pass it?

Comment: none?? okay.. will Parcelable work here? and if not, is it possible to store List<SpreadsheetEntry> in the sharedPrefrenes? the thing is I get the big list from the web, and I really don't want to make the API call twice because it takes a while.. and its in another activity

Comment: What information do you get from the backend-call?

Comment: I get a list of spreadsheets, and I dont want to makethis call twice (in each activity I look for a different spreadhseet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your code starting an activity, use an `AsyncTask`

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<SpreadsheetEntry>> myTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<SpreadsheetEntry>>()
        {
            @Override
            protected List<SpreadsheetEntry> doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                List<SpreadsheetEntry> entries;

                // Get your entries from internet here

                return entries;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<SpreadsheetEntry> myEntries)
            {
                SpreadsheetEntrySingleton.getInstance().setEntries(myEntries);

                startActivity(mUpdatePracticeIntent);
            }
        };

        myTask.execute();
```

**SpreadsheetEntrySingleton.java**

```
public class SpreadsheetEntrySingleton
{
    private static volatile SpreadsheetEntrySingleton _spreadsheetEntrySingleton;

    private List<SpreadsheetEntry> _entries;

    private SpreadsheetEntrySingleton()
    {
        super();
    }

    public static SpreadsheetEntrySingleton getInstance()
    {
        if (SpreadsheetEntrySingleton._spreadsheetEntrySingleton == null)
        {
            synchronized (SpreadsheetEntrySingleton.class)
            {
                if (SpreadsheetEntrySingleton._spreadsheetEntrySingleton == null)
                {
                    SpreadsheetEntrySingleton._spreadsheetEntrySingleton = new SpreadsheetEntrySingleton();
                }
            }
        }

        return SpreadsheetEntrySingleton._spreadsheetEntrySingleton;
    }

    public List<SpreadsheetEntry> getEntries()
    {
        return _entries;
    }

    public void setEntries(List<SpreadsheetEntry> list)
    {
        this._entries = list;
    }
}
```

And in the OnCreate() method of your `mUpdatePracticeIntent`, use `SpreadsheetEntrySingleton.getInstance().getEntries()` to get your entries.

Comment: thanks for your replay.. I am not quite sure what you mean. I know what singleton is, but how do I make it singleton and also pass in parameters on initialization? I need to get the list from the web at some point, and than initialize it... if you could show an short simple example for what you meant it would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Edited my answer. Since you're familiar with Singleton and Internet usage (you don't get "Internet on main thread" exception) I didn't explain the code. Please ask if you don't get it.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I used your code for the singleton and it works nicely :) one question - first time I want to work withthe list, I have to get it from the web. after that, I can use getEntries. is it "okay" to have a static boolean variable in the singleton class that wiill indicate if the list is set or not? because I am using it from many places, and the main thing is - I can't be sure what class will use it first. so I have to check before I do getEntries. thoughts?

Comment: @user1662033 You can use a static boolean that you set true inside the setEntries method (care, you could still pass an empty or null list and it would still set the boolean to true, you need to check if `SpreadsheetEntrySingleton.getInstance().getEntries()` isn't null and not empty).